# jQuery UI 1.9 milestone 6: how stable is it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

[jQuery UI 1.9 milestone 6](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui) has many new very useful features: menu, tooltips, popup and spinner (the last one not very useful for me).

I've tested it on Chrome and Firefox 8 and it works very nice.
But I can't test it on IE (because of Ubuntu).

Does anybody know how stable is it and could I use it in my real projects? And maybe somebody knows about release date of 1.9 version (I didn't find any information about release date)?

Comment: It's as stable as any pre-release version: less so than the final version.

Comment: Yeah, but maybe somebody has tested it on IE 6-9?

Answer (score 2):

I've used it on a project that was tested with IE8 and no problems were reported. That project used all the new components except tooltip.

The only problems we encountered were related to enhancing hidden elements, which are then subsequently displayed. This was resolved by changing the method of hiding (using ui-helper-hidden-accessible)